# Symfony, Doctrine update not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hey All I have this wired error that I cannot overcome. I am using Symfony Framweork and Doctrine for my DB interaction. I am trying to develop a simple CRUD API to grasp some of the concepts.

The actual problem is when I try to update an item in my DB it only works if the ID of the item is inside the DB else I get this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function setTitle() on a non-object
```

Have a look at my Repository:

```
<?php

namespace BooksApi\BookBundle\Repositories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException;

class UpdateBookRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    public $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager
    ){
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function updateBook($id, $update)
    {
        try {
            $book = $this->em->getRepository('BooksApiBookBundle:BooksEntity')
                ->find($id);

            $book->setTitle($update);
            $this->em->flush();
        } catch (\Exception $em) {
            throw new QueryException('003', 502);
        }

        return $book;
    }
}
```

And My factory:

```
<?php

namespace BooksApi\BookBundle\Repositories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException;

class UpdateBookRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    public $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager
    ){
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function updateBook($id, $update)
    {

        $book = $this->em->getRepository('BooksApiBookBundle:BooksEntity')
            ->find($id);

        if ($book)
        {
            try {
                $book->setTitle($update);
                $this->em->flush();
            } catch (\Exception $em) {
                throw new QueryException('003', 502);
            }

            return $book;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The factory handles the response true or false, So in event where I will try to update an Item thats ID is not in DB the factory should respond with `false, 'Unable to Update Book'` instead i get the above error, Any idea why guys..?

Comment: Obviously, the $book object is null. Did you check if you have that record in db?

Comment: The Object is updated if it exists in DB else I get the error above. But If you have a look in my Factory I did a case for it.... So instead seeing the error message i would expect to see { flase, Unable to Update Book } response.

Comment: The reason is that you do not check what `find()` does return (it is `null` if the book does not exist).

Comment: Consider adding some check of find results: Either `$book instanceof Book`, or `is_object($book)` before calling `$book->setTitle($update);`

Comment: are you sure that your request->get('id') return anything ?

Comment: OK i fixed it I understand the problem that I had, thanks to your suggestions, I updated my question which what I have now and works. basically the query failed because it could nnot find the id lol and i had no check for it :)

Answer (score 1):

@Tomazi, you can avoid error by checking if your object exists before calling "setTitle" method.

```
public function updateBook($id, $update)
{
    $book = $this->em->getRepository('BooksApiBookBundle:BooksEntity')->find($id);

    if ($book) {
        $book->setTitle($update);
        $this->em->flush();

        return $book;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Unfortanilly yout way did not work but it has lighten me up and changed your suggestion a bit which works now thanks for curving the path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that $book object is not empty before proceeding with the code. The error indicates that $book is null/empty.
Also, **persist** your object before using *flush*.

```
$this->em->persist($book);
$this->em->flush();
```